# Make words pulsate and change of place randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing this plugin that takes the words and makes them pulsate on the screen:

First they appear and grow, then they vanish, change place and again appear

Working plugin:

```js
+ function($) {

  var Pulsate = function(element) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.element = element;
    self.max = 70;
    self.min = 0;
    self.speed = 500;
    self.first = true;
    self.currentPlace;
    self.possiblePlaces = [
      {
        id: 0,
        top: 150,
        left: 150,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        top: 250,
        left: 250,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        top: 350,
        left: 350,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        top: 250,
        left: 750,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        top: 450,
        left: 950,
      }
    ];
    
  };
  
  Pulsate.prototype.defineRandomPlace = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.currentPlace = self.possiblePlaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * self.possiblePlaces.length)];
    
    if(!self.possiblePlaces) self.defineRandomPlace;
    
    
    
    self.element.css('top', self.currentPlace.top + 'px');
    self.element.css('left', self.currentPlace.left + 'px');
  };
  
  Pulsate.prototype.animateToZero = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.element.animate({
      'fontSize': 0,
      'queue': true
    }, self.speed, function() {
      self.defineRandomPlace();
    });
    
  };
  
  Pulsate.prototype.animateToRandomNumber = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.element.animate({
      'fontSize': Math.floor(Math.random() * (70 - 50 + 1) + 50),
      'queue': true
    }, self.speed, function() {
      self.first = false;
      self.start();
    });
  };
  
  Pulsate.prototype.start = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    if (self.first) self.defineRandomPlace();
    if (!self.first) self.animateToZero();
    
    self.animateToRandomNumber();
  };


  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('[data-pulsate]').each(function() {
      var element = $(this).data('pulsate') || false;
      
      if (element) {
        element = new Pulsate($(this));
        element.start();
      }

    });

  });

}(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  font-size: 0px;
}


.two {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
div {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<span class="word" data-pulsate="true">Love</span>
<span class="word" data-pulsate="true">Enjoy</span>
<span class="word" data-pulsate="true">Huggs</span>





<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you notice i define the places that the word can grow in the self.possiblePlaces, and if you notice the animation, sometimes more then one word can grow in one place, my goal coming here is ask for help. How I can make two words never grow in the same place??

I was trying to do like this:

In the defineRandomPlace i pick a random object inside my possiblePlaces array:

```
  Pulsate.prototype.defineRandomPlace = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.currentPlace = self.possiblePlaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * self.possiblePlaces.length)];

    if(!self.possiblePlaces) self.defineRandomPlace;


    delete self.possiblePlaces[self.currentPlace.id];
    self.element.css('top', self.currentPlace.top + 'px');
    self.element.css('left', self.currentPlace.left + 'px');
  };
```

Notice the delete, first i clone the chosen object, after I delete it but keep his place in the array.

After the animation was over, I put the object in the array again, before starting all over again:

```
  Pulsate.prototype.animateToZero = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.element.animate({
      'fontSize': 0,
      'queue': true
    }, self.speed, function() {
      self.possiblePlaces[self.currentPlace.id] = self.currentPlace;
      self.defineRandomPlace();
    });
```

But it made no difference.

Thanks!!

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waooQB

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdBBPE

Comment: that worked! Can you explain?

Comment: I'll explain in answer below ;)

Comment: The original design trapped you into a pattern. Working from a list of designated places, you can only make pattern more complex. Next time, go for truly random locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My decision is to divide the page to imaginary rows and to prohibit more than one word in the same row. Please check this out.

Note: as the code currently does not support recalculating of rows count on document resize, the full page view will not display correctly. Click "reload frame" or try [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtfupo4s/2/) or smth.

```js
var pulsar = {
  // Delay between words appearance
  delay: 400,
  // Word animation do not really depend on pulsar.delay,
  // but if you set pulsar.delay small and wordAnimationDuration long
  // some words will skip their turns. Try 1, 2, 3...
  wordAnimationDuration: 400 * 3,
  // Depending on maximum font size of words we calculate the number of rows
  // to which the window can be divided
  maxFontSize: 40,
  start: function () {
    this.computeRows();
    this.fillWords();
    this.animate();
  },
  // Calculate the height or row and store each row's properties in pulsar.rows
  computeRows: function () {
    var height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
    var rowsCount = Math.floor(height/this.maxFontSize);
    this.rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
      this.rows.push({
        index: i,
        isBusy: false
      });   
    }
  },
  // Store Word instances in pulsar.words
  fillWords: function () {
    this.words = [];
    var words = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pulsate="true"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      this.words.push(new Word(words[i], this.wordAnimationDuration, this.maxFontSize));
    }
  },
  // When it comes time to  animate another word we need to know which row to move it in
  // this random row should be empty at the moment
  getAnyEmptyRowIndex: function () {
    var emptyRows = this.rows.filter(function(row) {
      return !row.isBusy;
    });
    if (emptyRows.length == 0) {
      return -1;
    }
    var index = emptyRows[Math.floor(Math.random() * emptyRows.length)].index;
    this.rows[index].isBusy = true;
    return index;
  },
  // Here we manipulate words in order of pulsar.words array
  animate: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.interval = setInterval(function() {
      var ri = self.getAnyEmptyRowIndex();
      if (ri >= 0) {
        self.words.push(self.words.shift());
        self.words[0].animate(ri, function () {
          self.rows[ri].isBusy = false;
        });
      }
    }, this.delay);
  }
}

function Word (span, duration, maxFontSize) {
  this.span = span;
  this.inAction = false;
  this.duration = duration;
  this.maxFontSize = maxFontSize;
}

/** 
  * @row {Numer} is a number of imaginary row to place the word into
  * @callback {Function} to call on animation end
  */
Word.prototype.animate = function (row, callback) {
  var self = this;
  // Skip turn if the word is still busy in previous animation
  if (self.inAction) {
    return;   
  }
  var start = null,
      dur = self.duration,
      mfs = self.maxFontSize,
      top = row * mfs,
      // Random left offset (in %)
      left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90),
      // Vary then font size within half-max size and max size
      fs = mfs - Math.floor(Math.random() * mfs / 2);

  self.inAction = true;
  self.span.style.top = top + 'px';
  self.span.style.left = left + '%';

  function step (timestamp) {
    if (!start) start = timestamp;
    var progress = timestamp - start;
    // Calculate the factor that will change from 0 to 1, then from 1 to 0 during the animation process
    var factor = 1 - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(2 * Math.min(progress, dur) / dur - 1, 2));
    self.span.style.fontSize = fs * factor + 'px';
    if (progress < dur) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    else {
      self.inAction = false;
      callback();
    }
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

pulsar.start();
```

```css
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

.word {
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    font-size: 0px;
    /* To make height of the .word to equal it's font size */
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="word" data-pulsate="true">Love</span>
<span class="word" data-pulsate="true">Enjoy</span>
<span class="word" data-pulsate="true">Huggs</span>
<span class="word" data-pulsate="true">Peace</span>
```

Answer (score 8):

In your example, you are randomly picking from a list that has five members, and you have three separate words that could be displayed, putting chance of overlap fairly high.

A simple approach to resolve is to pick the first item in the list, remove it from the list, and the append to the end of the list each time.  Because you have more positions in the lists than items selecting from it, you're guaranteed to never collide.

1. Share the same list `possiblePlaces` between all instances.
2. Shift the first item off the queue, and push it onto the end when its done each time, instead of selecting randomly in `defineRandomPlace`.

Snippet highlighting #2:

```
// shift a position off the front
self.currentPlace = possiblePlaces.shift();

self.element.css('top', self.currentPlace.top + 'px');
self.element.css('left', self.currentPlace.left + 'px');

// push it back on the end
possiblePlaces.push(self.currentPlace);
```

If you want it truly random, you'll need to randomly select and remove an item from the array, and not put it back into the array until after it's been used.  You'll also need to always ensure that you have more `possiblePlaces` than you have dom elements to place on the page.

Like so:

```
Pulsate.prototype.defineRandomPlace = function() {
  var self = this;
  var newPlace = possiblePlaces.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*possiblePlaces.length), 1)[0];

  if (self.currentPlace) {
    possiblePlaces.push(self.currentPlace);
  }

  self.currentPlace = newPlace;

  self.element.css('top', self.currentPlace.top + 'px');
  self.element.css('left', self.currentPlace.left + 'px');
};
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdBBPE

Comment: That's very good Ben, but i need ask. Cant be total randomically? This is very good, really. But someone may notice that there is a pattern

Comment: Just to be clear, if i have for example 10 spots and 4 words, i can see any patterns, but if i have 10 spots and 9 words the pattern is very visible.

Comment: Yes you can make it truly random.  Updated.  The list of spots is still hardcoded however, so next step for you would be to figure out how to randomly define the possible places, and make sure they don't collide.  For another day.

Answer (score 2):

I updated your plugin constructor. Notice the variable `Pulsate.possiblePlaces`, I have changed the variable declaration this way to be able to share variable data for all Object instance of your plugin.

```
var Pulsate = function(element) {
    var self = this;

    self.element = element;
    self.max = 70;
    self.min = 0;
    self.speed = 500;
    self.first = true;
    self.currentPlace;
    Pulsate.possiblePlaces = [
        {
            id: 0,
            top: 150,
            left: 150,
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            top: 250,
            left: 250,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            top: 350,
            left: 350,
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            top: 250,
            left: 750,
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            top: 450,
            left: 950,
        }
    ];

};
```

I added `occupied` attribute to the possible places to identify those that are already occupied.  If the randomed `currentPlace` is already occupied, search for random place again.

```
Pulsate.prototype.defineRandomPlace = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.currentPlace = Pulsate.possiblePlaces[Math.floor(Math.random() * Pulsate.possiblePlaces.length)];

    if(!Pulsate.possiblePlaces) self.defineRandomPlace;


    if (!self.currentPlace.occupied) {
        self.currentPlace.occupied = true;
        self.element.css('top', self.currentPlace.top + 'px');
        self.element.css('left', self.currentPlace.left + 'px');
    } else {
        self.defineRandomPlace();
    }
};
```

Every time the element is hidden, set the `occupied` attribute to `false`.

```
Pulsate.prototype.animateToZero = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.element.animate({
        'fontSize': 0,
        'queue': true
    }, self.speed, function() {
        self.currentPlace.occupied = false;
        self.defineRandomPlace();
    });

 };
```

Answer (score 2):

A small hint f = 0.5px x = 100px t = 0.5s

```
x / f = 200
200/2 * t * 0.5 = f(shrink->expand until 100px square) per 0.5 seconds
```

Comment: If this is only a hint and not an answer, it should be be posted as a comment.